# Decomposability in the tensor product sense of functions of two variables

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functions

Let $S$ and $T$ be "nice" metric spaces, e.g. complete normed fields like $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb Q_p$.

Let $F$ be a function
$$
F:S\times T\longrightarrow K
$$
where $K$ is a topological field which has some nice regularity: let's say continuous or even differentiable or analytic whenever the concept applies.

Are there criteria to decide if there are functions $f:S\rightarrow K$ and $g:T\rightarrow K$ such that
$$
F(s,t)=f(s)g(t)\qquad\qquad\qquad(\ast)
$$
for all $(s,t)\in S\times T$?

In particular, I was thinking of something of this sort: if $F$ is $0$ everywhere, $(\ast)$ works obviously with $f\equiv0$ and $g\equiv0$, so assume there exists $(s',t')\in S\times T$ such that $F(s',t')\neq0$. Up to rescaling $F$ we may assume $F(s',t')=1$. Let
$$
f(s)=F(s,t'),\qquad g(t)=F(s',t).
$$
Are there non-tautological conditions under which $(\ast)$ holds?

Is the special case $S=T$ more treatable?

Of course, the problem is a special case of the problem of "recognizing" the vectors of the form $v\otimes w$ in a tensor product $V\otimes W$ ([see this SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128248/condition-for-a-tensor-to-be-decomposable)) except that now the spaces have infinite dimension.